# sed - how to replace line based on pattern?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sed

I have a `Macros` file which has, amongst other things, variable definitions like these:

```
SLIBS+=# USERDEFINED $(shell $(NETCDF_PATH)/bin/nc-config --flibs)

CFLAGS:= -gopt -Mlist -time
```

and I am trying to replace the contents of both `SLIBS+=` and `CFLAGS:=` using `sed`.

For example, I am trying to replace

```
SLIBS+=# USERDEFINED $(shell $(NETCDF_PATH)/bin/nc-config --flibs)
```

with

```
SLIBS+= -L/sw/arcts/centos7/netcdf/4.4.1/pgi-16.4-hdf5-1.8.16/lib -lnetcdff -L/sw/arcts/centos7/netcdf/4.4.1/pgi-16.4-hdf5-1.8.16/lib -L/sw/arcts/centos7/hdf5/1.8.16-pgi-16.4/lib -lnetcdf -lnetcdf -llapack -lblas
```

by using this command:

```
sed -i "s:SLIBS+=:SLIBS+= -L/sw/arcts/centos7/netcdf/4.4.1/pgi-16.4-hdf5-1.8.16/lib -lnetcdff -L/sw/arcts/centos7/netcdf/4.4.1/pgi-16.4-hdf5-1.8.16/lib -L/sw/arcts/centos7/hdf5/1.8.16-pgi-16.4/lib -lnetcdf -lnetcdf -llapack -lblas:g" Macros
```

but the new content is being **appended** to the old content, instead of **replacing** the old content.

What am I doing wrong?

Also, how could I do the same with the `CFLAGS` variable, replacing

```
CFLAGS:= -gopt -Mlist -time
```

with

```
CFLAGS:= -gopt -Mlist -time -I/sw/arcts/centos7/netcdf/4.4.1/pgi-16.4-hdf5-1.8.16/include -I/sw/arcts/centos7/hdf5/1.8.16-pgi-16.4/include
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just missing a regex subexpression to capture "whatever else is on the line after `SLIBS+=`". As a result, only *exactly* `SLIBS+=` is being replaced, and the text after that is remaining (so looks like its been appended).

Replacing your sed command with eg.

```
sed -i 's:SLIBS+=.*:SLIBS+= ... :g' Macros
```

should do the trick (note the added `.*` to match any number of other characters and the `'` to prevent the shell escaping `*`).

This approach should work for your `CFLAGS` as well.